# Unable to serialize the session state, was working, now isn't

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, session-state, datetimepicker

I used to be able to edit a record, click Save, and the record updates.  I had a couple jQuery datepicker's on my form - just standard `MM/dd/yyyy` format.  SQL didn't mind updating the SQL datetime with these.  Now, I added a timepicker addon (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).  So I go back to the same form, fill out my fields, click Save, and I get the ugly YSOD.  **The only difference is the format of the data in the fields representing the two dates.**  **What is weird is this only happens on an Edit.  A brand new record inserts just fine with the timepicker.**  Here's the YSOD and my new form fields representing the timepicker - I'm not showing the UI for the timepicker as that's not relevant, what's relevant is the data in the form field that is being passed back to SQL for an update:

[image]

[image]

I have a WebAPI sitting on a separate server that handles all of the CRUD operations.  Any ideas what's going on???

**EDIT**: Here's my Api POST controller method:

```
[HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutBulletinBoard(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            db.Entry(bulletinBoard).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked in what format this addon is passing datetime field to sql server ???

Comment: Error message is clear. You are putting into Session object that is not serializable.

Comment: @Peri, I understand what you're saying, but what's the difference between a POST and a PUT in this regard?  POST's work fine, PUT's do not.

Comment: But isn't the code that handles POST and PUT different?

Comment: @Peri Well sure, one adds a brand new record and one updates an existing record.  But speaking strictly on the datetime's - there shouldn't be a difference, right?

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged SQL-Server. You would be getting the same error message if you were using StateServer and not connecting to a database at all.

Comment: I don't think it's problem with date. Error message says it's session data not data you edit. If I remember well when you use SQL Server Session state all objects in Session are serialized and saved in one column in SQL Table. And here is the problem. It could help if you showed code for ApiController.

Comment: @Peri, I added the controller code.

Comment: You say it's POST but I see PUT. Please post both. Entire controller code.

Comment: I got it fixed.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had my Put method on my API controller as follows:

```
[HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutBulletinBoard(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
        {
```

The problem apparently was the name of the PUT method above - it needed to be:

```
[HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
        {
```

Because of some custom WebApiConfig.cs routes.  Out of the box, it's named as `PutBulletinBoard`, but I made some changes to the routing.

Comment: I wonder why the error was the way it was. Probably some other code was receiving PUT. You didn't show stacktrace from YSOD.